How can I convert a Lottie JSON file into an animated SVG?
I'm working on a project where I need to use an animation created in Lottie as an SVG for better compatibility with my web application. I have the Lottie JSON file and am looking for a way to convert it into an animated SVG.
I've tried searching for tools and libraries but haven't found a straightforward solution. Is there a method, library, or tool that can directly convert Lottie JSON to animated SVG format?
Things I've Tried:

I checked lottie-web but it seems to only render JSON animations as HTML elements and doesn't provide an option to export or convert to SVG.

Requirements:

I need the final SVG to retain the animation from the Lottie file.
Preferably, I want a solution that doesn't require complex post-processing of the SVG.
I'm open to using both JavaScript libraries or CLI tools for this conversion.


We don't allow questions about searching for tools or libraries I'm afraid.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hey have you found an answer yet?
